# Ejecutar ejecutable en servidor remotamente

Tags: visual, foxpro

Hola les cuento el problema que tengo, tengo un sistema cliente servidor instalado el cual fue desarrollado en Visual Foxpro 9.0, el servidor es un Windows Server 2016, y tengo terminales Cliente en windows 10 y windows 7.
Como puedo hacer yo para ejecutar el sistema desde los clientes remotamente en el servidor, es decir ejecutar el exe que esta en el servidor desde los clientes, pero aquí va lo principal de la pregunta.... ¿como puedo hacer esto sin tener que conectar la unidad de red en cada terminal cliente?
Espero haber sido claro con la consulta

Muchas gracias
Saludos!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Algo no cuadra aca.. lo que se ejecuta, esta en la pc que se ejecuta, salvo que sea web, que igual esta en la pc que se ejecuta, pero el renderizado capaz se hizo en el servidor... vos que queres ejecutar??? dijiste cliente servidor, con lo cual ejecutarias clientes en las pc de los clientes...

Comment: Cuando el exe se ejecuta y el programa se carga a memoria, este estaria en la memoria del cliente o del servidor?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola a todos muchas gracias por ayudarme les pido disculpas por la poca capacidad que tengo para hacerme entender, soy nuevo en stackoverflow, ya lo he solucionado era mas simple de lo que pensaba!
Saludos y muchísimas gracias!!!